# Javascript - check multiple times for condition with if and else if - working with Javascript objects and their properties

Tags: javascript, if-statement, javascript-objects

We have this Javascript object:

```
const recordCollection = {
  2468: {
    albumTitle: '1999',
    artist: 'Prince',
    tracks: ['1999', 'Little Red Corvette']
  },
  1245: {
    artist: 'Robert Palmer',
    tracks: []
  },
  5439: {
    albumTitle: 'ABBA Gold'
  }
};
```

To be able to update the properties of the object, one of the two functions could be used:

```
unction updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
  if (value === "") {
    delete records[id][prop];
  } else if (prop !== "tracks" && value !== "") {
    records[id][prop] = value;
  } else if (prop === "tracks" && value !== "") {
    if (records[id].hasOwnProperty("tracks") === false) {
      records[id][prop] = [];
    }
    records[id][prop].push(value);
  }
  return records;
}

let result = updateRecords(recordCollection, 2468, "tracks", "");
console.log(result);
```

OR

```
function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
   if (value === ""){ 
       delete records[id][prop];
   } else if(prop === "tracks" && value !== ""){
   records[id][prop] = records[id][prop] || [];
    records[id][prop].push(value);
  } else if(prop !== "tracks" && value !== "") {
    records[id][prop] = value;
  }
  return records;
}

let result = updateRecords(recordCollection, 2468, "tracks", "lala");
console.log(result);
```

Within the function, there's an initial check to see if a value is an empty string using ' if (value === "") '. Subsequent to this, two other conditions are examined, with the empty string condition consistently verified using the '&&' operator.

Is this repeated check for an empty string necessary? Can one safely remove the '&& value !== ""' part without introducing bugs or altering the intended functionality of the code?

If with and without are the same, which code would be better and why?

Please provide an explanation for your answer (whys and hows..). Thank you a lot!

I have already tried both versions with douple checking and without, but couldn't see a difference. This code is a solution for a Javascript exercise from freecodecamp. I have the specific questions I already mentioned, but any additional information is also welcomed! Thanks!

Comment: No, they're not necessary. If the first condition is false, then you know that `value` cannot be an empty string in the latter conditions. If it were an empty string, the first check would be true, the first `if` suite would be entered, and the latter conditions would never be checked. If they're checked, then the string cannot be empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the first `if (value === "")` evaluates to `false`, the subsequent `else if`s don't need to test if `value !== ""` because you can assume that to be the case by definition. So your first function can be simplified to:

```js
function updateRecords(records, id, prop, value) {
  if (value === "") {
    delete records[id][prop];
  } else if (prop !== "tracks") {
    records[id][prop] = value;
  } else if (prop === "tracks") {
    if (records[id].hasOwnProperty("tracks") === false) {
      records[id][prop] = [];
    }
    records[id][prop].push(value);
  }
  return records;
}
```

I would argue that this version of the code is better because it is shorter and less redundant.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to repeat opposite `if` conditions in `if else` since `if else` isn't executed if `if` is.

If you don't mind using 2 conditional operators you could do it in an arrow braceless function.
Since we access `records[id]` in every expression it would be nice to have a variable `record = records[id]`.
Since we decided to go without braces we can provide this variable as a default last parameter.
Since it's not used in the function call, that looks nice.
Also we have a problem here if there's no record with ID asked (`records[id]` is `undefined`) we have an error thrown and potentially crash our app. So there could a safe approach with automatically creating a record if it doesn't exist yet with `??=` operator.

```js
const updateRecords = (records, id, prop, value, record = records[id] ??= {}) =>
  !value ? delete record[prop] :
    prop === 'tracks' ? (record.tracks ??= []).push(value) : record[prop] = value;
    
    
const records = {};

updateRecords(records, 1, 'tracks', 'Hello world');

console.log(records);
```

```js
const updateRecords = (records, id, prop, value, record = records[id] ??= {}) =>
  !value ? delete record[prop] :
    record[prop] = prop === 'tracks' ? [...record.tracks ?? [], value] : value;
    
const records = {};

updateRecords(records, 1, 'tracks', 'Hello world');

console.log(records);
```

Comment: @DRA you should select one of the answers as accepted (the gray checkbox) that's how stackoverflow works, thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you please explain what you did exactly in this part "record = records[id] ??= {}"? Why have you passed that as a parameter as well to the inline funtion?

 I am not yet used with the ternary operator, so this will be a great opurtunity to study the code!!

Comment: @DRA added the description to the answer